# OpenCL device information collection

Tags: opencl, nvidia, amd-gpu

I would like to get an overview of what the OpenCL device limits are for current GPUs by Nvidia and AMD. I'm referring to the information which can be queried with [`clGetDeviceInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html), especially these:

- `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`
- `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`
- `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`
- `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE`

At least for the number of compute units there is some information on wikipedia, see e.g. for [AMD](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD-Radeon-HD-7000-Serie#Grafikprozessoren) (Column "Shader-Cluster"), but I would like a more condensed source with OpenCL-specific information.

Is there a good collection of OpenCL device information out there?

To be honest, I don't really expect to find something like that, because there are too many devices, different driver implementations, etc. which might influence what is accessible, but one can hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CompuBench](https://compubench.com/result.jsp) may be useful where not only the benchmark results can be found but also a `clGetDeviceInfo` like info, for example: [AMD Radeon™ R9 Series](https://compubench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=compu20&os=Windows&api=cl&D=AMD%20Radeon%20%28TM%29%20R9%20Series&testgroup=info)